# Rewrite the .aspx to .html

Tags: html, asp.net, aspx-user-control

I want to rewrite it to Html. can any one help me with that?

```
        <P><asp:label id="LabelAcronym" style="Z-INDEX: 103; LEFT: 38px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 158px"
                runat="server" Height="19px" Width="651px" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="StyleReportBody">Label</asp:label></P>
        <P><asp:label id="LabelDates" style="Z-INDEX: 104; LEFT: 38px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 218px"
                runat="server" Height="18px" Width="848px" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="StyleReportBody">Label</asp:label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</P>
        <P>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </P>
        <P><asp:label id="LabelAccountTitle" style="Z-INDEX: 100; LEFT: 38px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 138px"
                runat="server" Height="18px" Width="644px" Font-Size="Larger" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="StyleReportBodyBold">Label</asp:label>
            </P>
        <p>
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="lblProfitLossReport" runat="server" CssClass="StyleReportTitle" Style="left: 16px;
                position: absolute; top: 96px" Text="Profit & Loss Report" Width="328px"></asp:Label>
        </p>
<p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <asp:Table ID="DisplayTable" runat="server" CssClass="StyleReportBody" Width="1024px">
    </asp:Table>
    &nbsp;</p>
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CssClass="StyleReportBody" Width="1024px">
</asp:Table>
```

I have searched there are ways to move to browser and resave to html... I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Execute the page and view the source in the browser.

Comment: As Martino said, plus move any embedded CSS to stylesheets as well as bad HTML such as &nbsp; spacing.

Comment: HI i open them in internet explorer, and they are still aspx..

Comment: the code still get <asp:Content syntax

Comment: You are opening it as a normal file. You need to create an asp.net webform project , copy your code in the index.aspx page and compile it. Then you should be able to navigate to that page (something like http://localhost:portnumber/index.aspx) and view the source in the browser.